# How to fix "mainflipSelectors[i].find" error in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am building a webpage where I need to display some details about a few people. Each person's details is in the form of a card which goes by this structure:

```
<div class="mainflip">
    <div class="frontside">
        here goes the "frontside" code
    </div>
    <div class="backside">
        here goes the "backside" code
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the details of people are different, so the heights and widths of the "backside"(s) would be different (which, btw, contains the details of the persons). So to get those heights and widths, I wrote the following jQuery:

```
let mainflipSelectors = $('.mainflip');
for(let i = 0; i < mainflipSelectors.length; i++) {
    let backsideSelector = mainflipSelectors[i].find('.backside');
    let frontsideSelector = mainflipSelectors[i].find('.frontside');
    let backsideWidth = backsideSelector.width();
    let backsideHeight = backsideSelector.height();
    //here goes the rest of the code
}
```

But the above code throws out the error

> Uncaught TypeError: mainflipSelectors[i].find is not a function

I also tried

`let backsideSelector = mainflipSelectors[i].children().find('.backside');`

That throws

> Uncaught TypeError: mainflipSelectors[i].children is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use foreach instead. It might be a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mainflipSelectors[i]** returns the Html element and not the jQuery object.

You can use [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
mainflipSelectors.eq(i)
```

In any case I'd suggest to use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
let mainflipSelectors = $('.mainflip');
mainflipSelectors.each(function(idx, ele) {
    var currEle = $(ele);
    let backsideSelector = currEle.find('.backside');
    let frontsideSelector = currEle.find('.frontside');
    let backsideWidth = backsideSelector.width();
    let backsideHeight = backsideSelector.height();
    //here goes the rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This was exactly what I was looking for. The `.eq()` method worked perfectly fine. But yeah, for the sake of the readability of the code, will go by the `.each()` method.